# How to hide and visible the text content based on some value?

Tags: javascript, html

How to write HTML and Javascript code.
I have two text content like(Hi, Hlo how are you)& (I'm 5n what about you?).

When the values comes 3 need to show 1st content(Hi, hlo how are you).

If does not come value 3 need to show second content(l'm 5n what about you)..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is too broad to understand, where does this value come from? Is these text in same element or two different element? what you need covering few show hide use here:

1. Input from API call, with two div for two output:

HTML:

```
<div id="when3" class="hide">Hi, hlo how are you</div>
<div id="not3" class="hide">l'm 5n what about you</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Hide block */
.hide {
    display: none
}
```

JS:

```
let value = 3; //use user input here

function show() {
    if (value === 3) {
       document.getElementById("when3").classList.remove("hide");
       document.getElementById("not3").classList.add("hide");
    } else {
       document.getElementById("not3").classList.remove("hide");
       document.getElementById("when3").classList.add("hide");
    }
}

show();
```

2. When need to change value of same element based upon some input, no two different element:

HTML:

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

JS:

```
let value = 3; //use user input here

function show() {
    if (value === 3) {
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Hi, hlo how are you";
    } else {
       document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "l'm 5n what about you";
    }
}

show();
```

3. Show/Hide HTML `<div>` based upon some clicks. Used for navigation.

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li onclick="show('profile')">Profile</li>
   <li onclick="show('friends')">Profile</li>
   <li onclick="show('messages')">Profile</li>
</ul>
<div id="profile" class="hide">Profile Details</div>
<div id="friends" class="hide">Friends</div>
<div id="messages" class="hide">Messages</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Hide block */
.hide {
    display: none
}
```

JS:

```
function show(id) {
    hideAll();
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.classList.remove("hide");
}

function hideAll() {
    document.getElementById("profile").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("friends").classList.add("hide");
    document.getElementById("messages").classList.add("hide");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="sample"></div>
```

JS:

```
var test = document.getElementById("sample");
var value;

if(value === 3){
 test.innerHTML = "Hi, hlo how are you";
}
else{
 test.innerHTML = "l'm 5n what about you";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="text" id="txt"/><br/>
<input type="button" name="go" onClick="result()" value="send"/><br/>
<div id="msg"> </div>
```

javascript

```
function result(){
var test = document.getElementById("msg"); 
var value=document.getElementById("txt");

if(value === 3)
{
 test.innerHTML = "Hi, Hlo how are you";
}
else
{ 
 test.innerHTML = "l'm 5n what about you";
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```js
function showText(val, id) {
 document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = val == 3 ? "Hi, Hlo how are you" : "l'm 5n what about you";
}
showText(3, 'text');
showText(4, 'text1');
```

```html
<div id="text"></div>

<div id="text1"></div>
```